# Как отправить переменные через слеш библиотекой Volley?

Tags: java, android

Имеются 2 переменные. Как сделать запрос вида `site.com/String1/string2`?

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, site.com/, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

Пробовал добавлять слеш к первой переменной, но это ничего не даёт.

```
@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("String1", String1+"/");
                params.put("String2", String2);

                return params;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `site.com/` у вас должна быть переменная типа `String` с адресом. Вот в неё и добавляйте нужное:

```
String part1 = "part1";
String part2 = "part2";
String slesh = "/";
String url = "http://site.com" + slesh + part1 + slesh + part; 
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятен вопрос. Для вам добавлять слег? Если вам просто нужно отправить запрос с парметрами, то

```html
@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("String1", String1);
                params.put("String2", String2);

                return params;
            }
```

Этого вполне достаточно, либо можете попробовать так 'site.com/path?param1=value1&param2=value2'